# How to customize a Controller visual model in MRTK3 when the existing one doesn't fit the physical one I'm holding?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mrtk, htc-vive, oculusquest, openxr

I was wondering if I can customize the visual of a specific
controller model while using MRTK3?

I currently have two different VR Headsets which is Vive Focus 3 and Oculus Quest 2, both of them have problems when it comes to the visual which got decided and instantiated by the ControllerVisualizer class.

For Vive Focus 3, MRTK3 can't seem to find a proper model for it so proceed to use a generic fallback model which does not look like the
physic one in the real work and also has no animation for it too.

For Oculus Quest 2, MRTK3 does find a proper model for its controller but is somehow unable to load model animation. I guess this causes the model to despite having the correct shape of the physical one, the looks of it bugged out with it only having a pink color on the entire thing.

Does someone know how to swap out the visual model for a specific model or the correct way to fix this issue?

For Vive Focus 3, I tried to replace the generic fallback model with the one I found in Wave SDK, it did work in that case, but I'm not sure if this is the right solution since someone may use another controller which can be recognized by MRTK3 which leads to fallback model not being used.

For Oculus Quest 2, I tried to look figure out how MRTK3 find the correct model for it and where the model was stored, but due to a lack of knowledge and coding experience, I was not able to understand how things work in MRTK3......

Why methods in this class doesn't have any implementation in it?

```
public class ControllerModelArticulator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ControllerModelArticulator();

    public void StopArticulating();
    public bool TryStartArticulating(ControllerModel controllerModel, ulong modelKey);
    protected void Update();
}
```